# Drush install on local server error (Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level)

Tags: drupal, drush

I am getting an error message in Drush on a local mamp install

```
PDO::__construct(): [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306)             [warning]
environment.inc:517
Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more    [error]
functional Drupal environment to run this command.
The drush command 'en devel' could not be executed.                                                    [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                           [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case
you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no
access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
  Drupal version    : 7.21
  Site URI          : http://default
  Database driver   : mysql
  Database hostname : 127.0.0.1
  Database username : root
  Database name     : geoslate
  Default theme     : garland
  Administration theme: garland
  PHP configuration : /private/etc/php.ini
  Drush version     : 5.8
  Drush configuration: 
  Drupal root       : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geoslate
  Site path         : sites/default
  Modules path      : sites/all/modules
  Themes path       : sites/all/themes
  File directory path: sites/default/files
  %paths            : Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my drupal settings needed a port specifying which is on the MAMP home page and for me is 8889